# VIM startup, ignoring everything besides .vimrc

Tags: vim

I am logging in as a shared user and want to load vim settings specific to me.

I tried setting:

```
export VIMINIT='source ~myuser/.vimrc'
```

and also running with

```
vim -u ~myuser/.vimrc
```

Also tried this:

In all cases the .vimrc gets loaded correctly, however, I have bunch of other settings in ~myuser/.vim/*, like syntax highliting under .vim/syntax, etc.

All works fine when I am logged in as myuser, however, if i log in as shared user only .vimrc gets loaded but nothing else.

Howto get vim to load the whole ~myuser/.vim subdirectory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify the runtime path in your vimrc

```
set runtimepath=~myuser/.vim,$VIM/vimfiles,$VIMRUNTIME,$VIM/vimfiles/after,~myuser/.vim/after
```

This will change where vim looks for the .vim directory to ~myuser's vim directory. Make sure this line is run before any other line in your vimrc or else vim will look for runtime files in the default location. (Put it at or near the top of the file)

Comment: Still doesn't work, not sure why. Can you explain the settings posted?  Is it going to include: .vim/filetype.vim and .vim/syntax ?

Comment: @AdamSangala it should. Make sure that this line is near the top of you vimrc before you start calling other commands. This will affect where vim searches for runtime files. If you place the command too late in your vimrc vim will look for the files in the default locations.

Comment: @AdamSangala you might want to take a look at `:h 'runtimepath'`

Answer (score 0):

To make this work, you can try to symlink the other user's vim configuration to yours.

```
ln -s ~myuser/.vimrc ~/.vimrc 
ln -s ~myuser/.vim ~/.vim
```

this should work :)

Comment: Thanks Vdt, this is not an option for me as it would impact everybody using the shared user.

Answer (score 0):

Also check whether the shared user has access to `~myuser/.vim` and the files in it.

Comment: Yes, they are all accessible.